# Callbacks in IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, callback

I'm having an issue with callbacks and it's probably something I'm doing.  Using a JS class, I have an array of callbacks that I push functions into like:

```
obj.addCallback(function() { .. });
```

That works fine.  I try calling the function via:

```
var fns = this._callbacks;

if (fns != null) {
    for (var i = 0, len = fns.length; i < len; i++) {
        fns[i].apply(that, null);
    }
}
```

It gets to the apply of the function, but it never gets called.  This works in IE 9 and FF, but not IE 7/8.  How can I get it to work for all?

This is within an ASP.NET AJAX component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
fns[i].apply(that, null);
```

To

```
fns[i].apply(that, []);
```